# Microphone on my Ubuntu 22.04 OS is not working not even detecting headset

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, lenovo, 22.04, microphone

My microphone is not working on my Ubuntu 22.04 Lenovo IdeaPad laptop. I have my system dual booted and the microphone is working fine in Windows 10 Home, but it's not working in Ubuntu. The OS doesn't even detect my microphone when connected.

Any logs or anything will be provided based on this.

Results of  `pactl info` :

[image]

Results of `pulseaudio -v` :

[image]